# How can a Github workflow read a file on another private repository hosted on the same GitHub account?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a **private** git repository like:

`Github.com/acct/repo1`

I have a `test.json` file in another private repository in the same GitHub subscription and account like:

`Github.com/acct/repo2/test.json`

How can a workflow in `repo1` have http get access to the url `Github.com/acct/repo2/test.json`?

All I need is a simple way to read the content of `test.json` in a workflow running on `repo2`.

It works the best for me to read the file using a curl get request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to get an access token from GitHub. This is described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).

And add it to the secrets for the repository in which the Github Action will run. In your case, this is `repo1`. [Read more](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) about setting secrets.

After that, you can execute the request using `curl`.
To do this, run the following command:

```sh
  curl -H 'Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw' \
  -L https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER_HERE/REPO_NAME_HERE/contents/FOLDER_OR_FILE_HERE
```

After execution, the contents of the file will be displayed on the console.

If the contents of the file need to be saved to a variable, then use the following syntax:

```sh
  VARIABLE_NAME="$(curl -H 'Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw' \
  -L https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER_HERE/REPO_NAME_HERE/contents/FOLDER_OR_FILE_HERE)"
```

Add the `-O` flag to save the content to a file

```sh
  curl -H 'Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw' \
  -O \
  -L https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER_HERE/REPO_NAME_HERE/contents/FOLDER_OR_FILE_HERE
```

In your case, the step in the `.yml` file to get the content would look like this:

```yaml
#...
-name: Get file test.json
 run: |
   curl -H 'Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
   -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw' \
   -O \
   -L https://api.github.com/repos/acct/repo2/contents/test.json
#...
```

Please note that the path `/contents/` must remain after `REPO_NAME_HERE` in the request, and after that you can specify the path to the `FOLDER_OR_FILE_HERE` file.